# How to animate fa icon change?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, .net-core, blazor

https://imgflip.com/gif/3qzcjs
I want to change fa icon when this menu is expanded.
I tried to change the class but the image doesn't change.

```
         <ul class="list-unstyled components">
             <li>
                 <NavLink href="/">
                     Acasă
                 </NavLink>
             </li>
             <li>
                 <a @onclick="(() => ToggleNav(1))" data-toggle="collapse">Articole <i class="fa @(this.IsHidden1 ? "fa-angle-right" : "fa-angle-down")"></i></a>
                 <ul class="list-unstyled sub-menu @(this.IsHidden1 ? "toggle-hide": "toggle-show")">
                     <li>
                         <NavLink class="testclass" href="/sdfds">
                             SubMenu1
                         </NavLink>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                         <NavLink class="testclass" href="/sdfds">
                             SubMenu2
                         </NavLink>
                     </li>
                 </ul>
             </li>
</ul>


 @code {
     protected bool IsHidden1 { get; set; } = true;

     protected void ToggleNav(int navId)
     {
         switch (navId)
         {
             case 1:
                 IsHidden1 = !IsHidden1;
                 break;
         }
     }
 }
```

I tried to call StateHasChanged(); but doesn't work too.
Can you help me animating that icon onclick?

Comment: Your code is missing a closing </ul>. Once fixed, your code is working for me (provided classes toggle-hide, toggle-show, fa-angle-right and fa-angle-down are correctly loaded.

Comment: It doesn't work. I had </ul> in my code.

Comment: Is your project Blazor WASM or Server? Did you checked for any javascript error in console? I did `dotnet new blazorwasm`, copied your code in `index.blazor` and it just ran I'm on `.net core 3.1.2`. See demonstration: https://youtu.be/2x0Dczf4J6M.

Comment: Hi! Thank you Claudio. It's a Server. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dLZqq2VAkLg

Comment: Still works for me in blazorserver too :\ Same process as above. Did you notice that "An unhanded exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details" message? What is dev tools window saying? (maybe edit question with exception message)